# unique values from two columns ma access - unique values from second column

Tags: ms-access, compare, unique, ms-access-2016

I have 2 columns in Microsoft Access table
and now i need to compare and find a list of unique values from this two columns
How can i do it ?
get only unique values from second column
please help
Thank You
[**Image here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Roh1.jpg)

Everything I could do, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

As to your sample, you can simply do:

```sql
Select [Column B] From YourTable
Where [Column A] Is Null
```

or:

```sql
Select [Column B] From YourTable
Where [Column B] > 
    (Select Max(T.[Column A]) From YourTable As T)
```